# typedef shared_ptr<T> conversion to bool

Tags: c++, visual-c++, shared-ptr

I have a typedefined shared_ptr<> which I am using in a conditional check.

This is how it is defined:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<T> typeTPtr;
```

Then I am passing it to a function taking a bool argument:

```
void Foo(bool);
```

When I try to do:

```
typeTPtr ptrT = ...
Foo(ptrT);
```

I get the error an error saying

> cannot convert argument from T to bool

I believe std::shared_ptr has bool operator explicitly defined. 
Why is the compiler not converting shared_ptr to bool?
I am using Visual C++ 2017

Thank you.

Comment: I guess that both answers are correct, so one of them should be accepted!

Answer (score 3):

It indeed does have an operator `bool`, but this operator is `explicit`, so you should perform a cast:

```
foo(static_cast<bool>(ptr));
```

Note that there is no need for a cast inside of `if` statement because it is considered an explicit conversion.

Answer (score 2):

The [`operator bool()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_bool) of `shared_ptr` is marked `explicit`. So implicit conversions are not possible.

Use a `static_cast` instead for explicit conversion.